# Adding category-brand to product title in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress

Okay so here is the deal guys. I am trying to add brand to the product title at the category page. The code i got right now adds an attribute, but I can't seem to choose which one it chooses. What do I need to change to be able to choose the show only the brand category?

function category_single_product(){

```
$product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );

if ( $product_cats && ! is_wp_error ( $product_cats ) ){

    $single_cat = array_shift( $product_cats ); ?>

    <h2 itemprop="name" class="product_category_title"><span><?php echo $single_cat->name; ?></span></h2>
```